# How to divide two columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How generate this SQL, with sqlalchemy

```
SELECT SUM(click) / SUM(impression) as my_indicator
FROM stats;
```

```
session.query(
    func.sum(table.click).label("click"),
    func.sum(table.impression).label("impression"),
    # ??? sum(click) / sum(impression) ???
).group_by(table.type)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import label

session.query(
    label('my_indicator', sum(click) / sum(impression))
).group_by(table.type)
```

Comment: Can you add description that helps the original poster and anybody searching stackoverflow to understand your code?

Comment: While this code snippet might help solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) would really help improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion - providing an overview of why you think this will work or where to place the code is recommended.