# SQL Alchemy - hybrid properties - splitting a column

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I was wondering if anybody knows how to split a column in sqlalchemy to create a calculated field.

Tried:

```
class Pupils(db.Model):
    full_name = db.Column(db.Text) #Jonh Doe

@hybrid_property
def firstname(self):
    return self.full_name.split(" ")[0]
```

However, I receive the error message:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Pupils.full_name has an attribute 'split'
```

I was wondering what I was doing wrong? My fingers are bloody from Googling...Captain! please help!

Comment: You saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650846/how-to-divide-two-columns-in-sqlalchemy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974069/sqlalchemy-how-to-divide-2-columns-from-different-table ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from sqlalchemy import func

class Pupils(db.Model):
    full_name = db.Column(db.Text) #Jonh Doe

@hybrid_property
def firstname(self):
    return func.split_part(self.full_name, ' ', 1)
```